# Is the apostrophe placed before or after "and" in this instance?

Tags: conjunctions, apostrophe

Like when something belongs to (or has a relationship with) two people.

```
"Dan and Jack's mother"
"Dan's and Jack's mother"
```

Which one is correct? Would it be the same or different with more than two?

PS: Google did not bring up anything.

Comment: Both are possible, idiomatic, and common. See the linked question for details.

Comment: Thank you for the link!